# Bind JPanel side with another JPanel Center

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, user-interface, layout-manager

Hi I am building a UI for a project and I have a JPanel which I want to divide into two equal parts. I am trying to find a way to add two small JPanel inside the big one but I don't know how to bind one side of a JPanel with the center of a bigger one. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to find a way to add two small JPanel inside the big one

Use a GridLayout on the big panel. The layout manager will automatically make both panels the same size. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).